# In Flink Process files one after another and update a common java object after every file processing

Tags: java, dataset, apache-flink

I have to get data from multiple data files and create a single record in a sink file, basically a static `java.util.List`.

If I specify `env.execute` after each data set,the java object is refreshed after each file process

If I specify `env.execute` finally,file processing happens parallel and I get wrong manipulation of data finally.

Any suggestions?

```
 try {
        scanDirectory();
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        for(int i =0;i<fileArray.length;i++) {
            DataStream<String> text = env.readTextFile(fileArray[i].getPath());
            System.out.println(fileArray[i].getPath());
            if(fileArray[i].getName().contains("post")) {
                DataStream<String> DataStream = text.flatMap(new WirlsChargesPostBillMapper());
            //  DataStream.writeAsText("C:\\Users\\workspace\\POC\\resources\\results.txt");
            //  env.execute("First FLink POC");
            }

            if(fileArray[i].getName().contains("pre")) {
                DataStream<String> DataStream2 = text.flatMap(new WirlsChargesPreBillMapper());
            //  DataStream2.writeAsText("C:\\Users\\workspace\\POC\\resources\\results1.txt");
            //  env.execute("First FLink POC");
            }
            //  DataStream<String> keysStream = DataStream.forward();
        //  keysStream.writeUsingOutputFormat(new JedisOutputFormat(null));
        //  logger.info("final class"+LineDumpList.get(0).getBanNumber());
            env.execute("First FLink POC");
        }`
```

Comment: unclear what you're asking. Why can't you just create multiple `DataSet` objects, one for each file?

Comment: I do create mutilple datasets..i need col A,B from one file ..Col C,D corresponding to col A from second file..couldn't construct this with the above code

Comment: and using a join on column `A` does not work why?

Comment: dataset1<A,B>;dataset2<A,C>     I need a third dataset3<A,B,C>  ...Join produces <A,B>,<A,C>

Comment: Join Produces,                                                                                                                       ((534090974608,8.99),(534090974608,LTPYM))
((534116298720,0.76),(534116298720,LFGHHJ))                                                                       I need                                                                                                                              ((534090974608,8.99,LTPYM))
((534116298720,0.76,LFGHHJ))

Comment: you should start reading the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#join) ...`input1.join(input2).where(0).equalTo(0).projectFirst(0,1).projectSecond(1);`